# Anyone used to work with Web Scraping in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('/api', function() {
    $crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/wholesale-magnetic-charging-cable-flowing-light_62127638796.html?spm=a2700.details.deiletai6.5.472ada1akNmbnG&bypass=true');

    $crawler->filter('.ma-title')->each(function ($node) {
        dump($node->text());
    });
});
```

I don't always receive data and sometimes I need to refresh 10 times to get data.

Can anyone advise why this might be?

Comment: Does every request fail, or just some requests? It's probable that Alibaba are throttling, if not blocking requests entirely to prevent scraping.

Comment: not all request fail sometimes get data sometimes not

Comment: And when there's no data, what's returned instead? What's the response code in such instances?

Comment: Try another website than alibaba, a more "simpel, local webshop" and see if the same happens. If not, it most likely has something to do with Alibaba, like @fubar is indicating.

Comment: I see that the <h1> (.ma-title) object is rendered as per ajax request. Try .tiny-title div and the <p> object inside that  instead. Might be because of that